# WPF TabControl and Data Templates

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datatemplate

Fairly new to the world of WPF. I've got data binding to a view model in the past just fine when it's a basic tree of elements under the root .

Like this works fine:

```
<TextBox x:Name="emailTxt" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=Email}">
```

My Email string object binds and displays in the above textbox appropriately.

However, when using a DataTemplate nothing seems to work. I'm not sure if its a combination of not implementing the DataTemplate correctly or something with the TabControl. I've tried switching around the logic a bit based on other sources (setting DataType on the template, etc), but that's been no good.

Here's the example of kind of what I have currently (sorry the template is long do the needing a large grid of 3x40 cells): this template exists under Windows.Resources.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="commGridTemplate" DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:CommViewModel}">
        <ScrollViewer Margin="10,30,60,30">
            <Grid Name="CommGrid" IsSharedSizeScope="True"> <!-- DataContext="{Binding}" -->
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Name="RowBoxCol" Width="0.2*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Name="ChannelCol" Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Name="FrequencyCol" Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Name="DescriptionCol"  Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <!--#region Row Definitions-->
                    <RowDefinition Height="20" SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition> <!-- Header Row-->
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommRow"></RowDefinition>
                    <!--#endregion Row Definitions-->
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                
                <!-- Header boxes-->
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True" Text="Channel"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True" Text="Frequency"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True" Text="Description"></TextBox>
                
                <!--#region Content boxes-->
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox x:Name="ExampleBox" Text="{Binding Path=ExampleText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="4" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="6" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="6" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="6" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="7" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="7" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="7" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="8" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="8" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="8" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="8" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="9" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="9" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="9" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="9" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="10" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="10" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="10" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="10" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="11" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="11" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="11" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="11" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="12" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="12" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="12" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="12" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="13" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="13" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="13" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="13" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="14" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="14" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="14" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="14" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="15" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="15" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="15" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="15" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="16" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="16" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="16" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="16" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="17" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="17" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="17" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="17" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="18" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="18" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="18" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="18" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="19" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="19" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="19" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="19" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="20" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="20" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="20" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="20" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="21" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="21" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="21" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="21" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="22" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="22" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="22" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="22" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="23" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="23" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="23" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="23" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="24" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="24" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="24" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="24" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="25" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="25" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="25" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="25" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="26" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="26" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="26" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="26" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="27" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="27" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="27" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="27" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="28" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="28" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="28" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="28" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="29" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="29" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="29" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="29" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="30" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="30" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="30" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="30" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="31" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="31" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="31" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="31" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="32" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="32" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="32" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="32" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="33" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="33" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="33" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="33" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="34" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="34" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="34" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="34" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="35" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="35" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="35" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="35" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="36" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="36" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="36" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="36" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="37" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="37" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="37" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="37" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="38" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="38" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="38" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="38" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="39" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="39" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="39" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="39" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HeaderFiller}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="40" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="40" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="40" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="40" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <!--#endregion-->
                
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </DataTemplate>

<Grid Name="MainWindowGrid">
    <GroupBox Style="{DynamicResource GroupBoxStyleNoHeader}" BorderThickness="1" Margin="10,25,10,10">
        <Grid Name="GroupBoxGrid">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition x:Name="tabControlRow" Height="14*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition x:Name="formButtonsRow" SharedSizeGroup="A"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TabControl Name="CommTabs" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5,10,5,0" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource commGridTemplate}">

                <TabItem Name="UHFTab" Header="UHF" Padding="15,2,15,2"/>
                <TabItem Name="VHFTab" Header="VHF" Padding="15,2,15,2"/>
            </TabControl>
```

Right now I'm just trying to get the ExampleBox at Grid 1,1 to bind to the ExampleText object that exists within my CommViewModel. I set a namespace at the top for **xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:CommGUI.ViewModels"** so hopefully it's accessible. I also set ViewModel as the DataContext of the main window within MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
 ViewModels.CommViewModel viewModel = new ViewModels.CommViewModel(Convert.ToString(id));
        this.DataContext = viewModel;
```

Any input would be much appreciated.

**EDIT: ** In response to a comment: my grid is a 3x40 consisting of all textboxes. 3 columns, 40 rows. The top row is made up of disabled boxes to act as the header for each column. The columns are Channel, Frequency, and Description. I imagine each row will contain data from a bound object from CommViewModel.

[GUI Mock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TltCI.png)

Comment: Lets step back a bit...  your grid is 3x40?  Edit your existing post, dont put it in comment.  Can you post context of what you are trying to present in the grid (vs possibly a datagrid).  Why 3x40.  Can you post an example of the context of a single record?  Or is it each column represents the repeated data that is on 3 rows?  That might help me or others better offer a solution for your needs.  Just give us context of what you are TRYING to get output for.  I see channel, frequency and description, but no sample data, even if text to show.

Comment: Updated with some more info.

Comment: You definitely want to use the [DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid?view=windowsdesktop-6.0). Visit the link and scroll down to the Remarks section to find an image of a rendered example. As a developer or programmer you should always feel alarmed when you have to write repeated code, especially at this degeree of repetitiveness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are going about it the wrong way.  What you probably need is to create a List that has the 3 parts you need... Frequency, description, and any other things you want.  Make the List<> public via a getter/setter.

In your form, create a DataGrid control and set its items source to the List<> and you are almost done.

I have created a sample project called Help1, so change the context, or copy paste into your project to see it work.  Below is the MainWindow.xaml showing the use of a datagrid.

```
<Window 
    x:Class="Help1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Help1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Grid>

        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding AllMyChannels}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding JustTheOneChosenInTheGrid}" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False">

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Channel"  Width="70"
                    CanUserSort="True" Binding="{Binding Channel}" />


                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Frequency"  Width="100"
                    CanUserSort="True" Binding="{Binding Frequency}" />

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description"  Width="200"
                    CanUserSort="True" Binding="{Binding Description}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now, the codebehind via MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace Help1
{
    public partial class MainWindow 
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            prepareChannels();
            DataContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public List<YourStuff> AllMyChannels { get; set; }
        private void prepareChannels()
        {
            AllMyChannels = new List<YourStuff>();
            AllMyChannels.Add(new YourStuff { Channel = "x1", Frequency = 98.7m, Description = "Some radio station" });
            AllMyChannels.Add(new YourStuff { Channel = "y2", Frequency = 16.7m, Description = "Another Thing" });
            AllMyChannels.Add(new YourStuff { Channel = "z9", Frequency = 2320.3m, Description = "who knows" });
            // continue with all other frequency / items you have, or pull from some database somewhere.
        }

        // a public object reference to hold whatever the current selected item would be wihtin a datagrid
        private YourStuff _justTheOneChosenInTheGrid = null;
        public YourStuff JustTheOneChosenInTheGrid
        {
            get { return _justTheOneChosenInTheGrid; }
            set { _justTheOneChosenInTheGrid = value;

                // anything you might want to do with the record the user just changed to
                MessageBox.Show($"Just selected Channel: {_justTheOneChosenInTheGrid.Channel}");
            }
        }
    }

    // define your own class listing the things you want to present to the user.
    public class YourStuff
    {
        public string Channel { get; set; } = "";
        public Decimal Frequency{ get; set; } = 0;
        public string Description { get; set; } = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this concise answer! While it doesn't answer the "how to bind the view model to a DataTemplate," it help me think of the root issue in what I was trying to accomplish. Your approach of a Datagrid and binding the ItemSource appropriately to the data objects works well. I shouldn't even need a DataTemplate now.

Comment: @whizkid75, glad it works.  Now, what I gave you is a baseline.  You can look into STYLE Templates that you can make your data grids look like with formatting and other stuff as well.